# Error 26 ambiguous reference VS2012

Tags: c#

> Error 26 'ProductFact' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Adcheck.ServiceReference1.ProductFact' and
>   'SLAdcheckBusinnesObjects.Facts.ProductFact' D:\Factory\factory
>   code\BMI\Adcheck\Adcheck\Controls\Contents\CaptureProductVolumesPerPack.xaml.cs
>   ‌​41 62 Adcheck

```
using SLAdcheckBusinnesObjects.Products;
using SLAdcheckBusinnesObjects.Facts;


namespace Adcheck.Controls.Contents
{
    public partial class CaptureProductVolumesPerPack : SecurityEnabledPage
    {           
        private List<ProductFact> newProductFacts = new List<ProductFact>();

        public CaptureProductVolumesPerPack()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InnerLayoutRootHeader.IsHitTestVisible = false;

             Page p = Application.Current.RootVisual as Page; 

                    if(p != null)  // p is the Page UserControl.
                    {

                    }
```

Comment: take more care formatting your question! and whats the question???#

Comment: Error 26 'ProductFact' is an ambiguous reference between 'Adcheck.ServiceReference1.ProductFact' and 'SLAdcheckBusinnesObjects.Facts.ProductFact' D:\Factory\factory code\BMI\Adcheck\Adcheck\Controls\Contents\CaptureProductVolumesPerPack.xaml.cs 41 62 Adcheck

Comment: Aybie - Please give us some context on what you are doing.  You cannot expect anyone to help you if you don't put in some effort formatting your code and explaining the issue at hand.

Comment: ok, i'm debugging this program here. it has tons of errors, managed to fix a few but when i fix one another one comes up. i'm so confused right i don't know what do anymore please pardon me for my incomprehensibility . wish i could give you the program and have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProductFact` is ambiguous, you need to qualify it with either    `SLAdcheckBusinnesObjects.Facts.ProductFact` or `Adcheck.ServiceReference1.ProductFact`

for example:

```
 private List<SLAdcheckBusinnesObjects.Facts.ProductFact> newProductFacts = new List<SLAdcheckBusinnesObjects.Facts.ProductFact>();
```

Comment: if it answers your question, you should upvote my answer and D Stanleys. You should mark the best answer by ticking the green arrow.

Comment: thanks for marking as answered. For your next question reading this might improve the question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a service reference that is creating types based on the service definition, and you are *also* referencing the assembly from the assembly that defines those types on the service side.  The two main options are:

1. Use namespaces to distinguish the two types, or
2. Check the "Reuse types from referenced assemblies" option when creating the service reference.